# When a Cleric spontaneously casts a Cure Light Wounds spell, will a Pearl of Power recover the original spell or Cure Light Wounds?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, magic-items

Assume a cleric has converted one of their first level spells into *cure light wounds*, and it was the only spell they have expended. When they use the *pearl of power* to recover the spell, what is recovered: the original spell, or the *cure light wounds*?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### The cleric recovers the original spell…

On [Spontaneous Casting](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/Cleric/#Spontaneous-Casting) says

> The cleric can 'lose' any prepared spell that is not an orison or domain spell in order to cast any *cure* spell of the same spell level or lower (a *cure* spell is any spell with 'cure' in its name).

The *cure* spell that was spontaneously cast wasn't prepared. The original spell was. The description of the [*pearl of power*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/m-p/pearl-of-power/), in part, says

> Once per day on command, a *pearl of power* enables the possessor to recall any one spell that she had prepared and then cast that day. The spell is then prepared again, just as if it had not been cast.

Thus using the *pearl* restores the original spell… that the cleric can then expend *again* to spontaneously cast a *cure* spell, if she so desires.

#### …Or, strictly, *neither* spell

A comment by [Ilmari Karonen](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/2620/ilmari-karonen) pointed out a quirk in the pearl's description. A GM could read part of the *pearl*'s description—that it "enables the possessor to recall any one spell that she had prepared *and then cast* that day" (emphasis mine)—as it forbidding the caster from using the *pearl* to recall a spell that was "lost" due to spontaneous casting.

This GM and player doesn't endorse such a reading, but in, for example, a campaign dominated by casters with the ability to spontaneously cast spells, this GM could imagine another GM going with such a literal reading.

Comment: Wouldn't a literal reading of your second quote (specifically, the "prepared and then cast" part) imply that a _pearl of power_ is simply not usable in this case, since the spell was "lost" instead of being cast?

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Sadly, literally it would. However, since that's *Third Edition* language I think that's an accidental byproduct of cutting down while also expanding the *2e* description of the *pearl* (it "enables the possessor to recall any one spell as desired, even if the spell has already been cast. Of course, the wizard must have the spell to be remembered among those most recently memorized" (*Encyclopedia Magica* 3538–9)) rather than a purposeful attempt to, for instance, limit the *pearl*'s use due to cleric or druid spontaneous casting.

Comment: @TigerDM Um. I don't think that's accurate: "This seemingly normal pearl of average size and luster is a potent aid to all spellcasters who prepare spells (clerics, druids, rangers, paladins, and wizards). Once per day on command, a pearl of power enables the possessor to recall any one spell that she had prepared and then cast." (See [here.](http://dndsrd.net/magicItemsWI.html#pearl-of-power) *Pathfinder* left the *pearl* largely untouched.)

Comment: @TigerDM (The *pearl of power* for casters who don't prepare spells at all is in *3.5* the *memento magica* (*Magic Item Compendium* 164). At about 25% cheaper than a *pearl*, it only recalls an empty slot; it specifically "has no effect for spellcasters who prepare their spells." The *Pathfinder* version of the *memento* is, I think, the similar [*runestones of power*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/r-z/runestone-of-power/) that aren't less expensive and significantly less versatile.)

Comment: I meant “can’t” haha, apologies! That they changed it to the Runestone of power makes sense, good point :)

Comment: @TigerDM Darn you, man! That `'t` cost me, like, 150 words! `:-)`